# Show image colored on hover

Tags: jquery, css, hover

How can i show image colored on mouseover?

My questions is similar to this jQuery script i follow for recursively changing images.

- A grayscale image
- A colored image

  ```
  $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#image").hover(function () {
            $(this).attr("src", "tpi/colored.jpg");
        }, function () {
            $(this).attr("src", "tpi/grayscale.jpg");

        });
    });
  ```

Now is there any other way in css or jQuery with that i could do this without using two images at a time on hover?

Comment: Did i forget mentioning "I don't want to use two images" ? Why people answering me awkward.

Comment: @Manoz Look at my link. Only uses one image for most browsers, two for Firefox if you count an SVG filter.

Comment: OP, why edited post with again crazy indentation?

Comment: @Nile , surely the best i could do with.

Answer (score 2):

Working **DEMO** in chrome http://jsfiddle.net/HF8c7/

```
-webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
```

Comment: thankyou, so it has no cross-browser compatibility?

Comment: I have not checked it

Comment: for others, you may use rgba() to get to a close result: http://codepen.io/gcyrillus/pen/nqpDd , You have SVG filters as well avalaible for Firefox for instance